# Closing a parents view controller

Tags: swift

If view controller (A) is presented modally (slide up) and can segue to view controller (B) via the .FlipHorizontal segue, how can I close view controller (B) to slide down (as closing view controller A would)

In other words,

-->modal (slide up)--> v.c (A)

(A)-->modal(flipHorizontal)--> (B)

how to dismiss v.c (B) to slide down

Answer (score 0):

You need to unwind the segue.

Write this code in the view controller file that you want to go back to (A):

```
@IBAction func unwindToPreviousScreen(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

}
```

After writing this code, go to the storyboard, and go to view controller that is the one you don't want to go back to (B), and control-drag from the view controller to the exit icon in the tab bar of the view controller (far right icon). Make sure you have clicked on the view controller.

It doesn't have to be unwindToPreviousScreen, it can be whatever you like, but be sure to keep the unwindTo part intact.